# How to check the filename before paste the new file in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Situation:

I have **folder 1** and **folder 2**.

folder 1 will do one job -> cut paste and replace without checking the filename already exist in folder 2 or not. If my folder 1 have file.pdf to cut paste to folder 2 and my folder 2 also have file.pdf

How to replace my folder 2 file.pdf to example file_a.pdf before file.pdf paste on it in .bat
and one more situation here is my filename.pdf will be generate randomly cannot hardcode like example(file.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

IF EXIST "C:\Users\Tabby-PC\Documents\hey.pdf" goto :sus 

copy "C:\Users\Tabby-PC\Downloads\hey.pdf" "C:\Users\Tabby-PC\Documents"

echo Well... The File Is Copied.. SUCESSFULLY

timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul &exit

:sus

copy C:\Users\Tabby-PC\Downloads\hey.pdf C:\Users\Tabby-PC\Documents\hey-a.pdf

echo There was an existing file With the same File Name... So The file was renamed and Copied SUCESSFULLY

timeout /t 5 /nobreak >nul &exit
```

Try The code Above.. All it does is It check if the file is existing in the destination ( in which yours is folder 2 ). If it has a File with the same name,it will rename it and then paste it...  :)

*If the above code Has Errors, Pls Let me Know...*

~Tabby

Comment: The `echo` lines i e `echo Well... The File Is Copied.. SUCESSFULLY` is an assumption. You do not know if it was successful, what if the file is locked or access denied? You will then always state success, even if it failed. You need to work of the `errorlevel`. Also, double quote your paths, always.

Comment: oh.. ye  : ( ill edit that... ill make a errorlevel to check if its completed. but it wont really be nesessary for his scenario... so yeah... anyways tnx

Comment: It is necessary. You cannot tell the user it is successful if it failed for many possibile reason. So giving a blind statement that it was successful is incorrect.

Comment: hi tabby thank for answering. if my pdf is generate the name randomly cannot be hardcode like what you show here -> IF EXIST "C:\Users\Tabby-PC\Documents\hey.pdf.